# Why order of decomposition group＝$[L:K]/$(number of prime ideal above $ \mathfrak p$)

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a finite **galois** extension of number field.

Let $\mathfrak p$ be prime ideal of $K$ .$$D_{\mathfrak p} = \{ \sigma \in G : \sigma(\mathfrak p) = \mathfrak p\}$$ be decomposition group.

Could you tell me proof of $♯D_{\mathfrak p}＝[L:K]/$(number of prime ideal above $ \mathfrak p$) holds ?

Maybe simple observation may deduce this, I'm having trouble relating decomposition group and number of prime ideal above $ \mathfrak p$.

Comment: The extension needs to be Galois.

Comment: The decomposition group is defined by an ideal in the bigger field, not in the smaller field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's well-known that the action of $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ on the set $X$ of prime ideals above $\mathfrak{p}$ is transitive. Now fix a prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ above $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $D_\mathfrak{P}$ is the stabiliser of $\mathfrak{P} \in X$ and so the orbit-stabiliser theorem implies what we want.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. Could you tell me a sketch of proof why $Gal(L/K)$ acts transitively on prime ideals above $ \mathfrak {p}$ ?

Comment: Reference book is also appreciated.

Comment: @dandelion this is a standard fact and it is probably found in almost any text on algebraic number theory. You can for example look in Neukirch.